# Import blogspot posts to Jekyll

Tags: jekyll, blogspot

I imported my posts from blogger to my jekyll blog using [this](http://import.jekyllrb.com/docs/blogger/) instructions. Unfortunetly it's in pure HTML format not in my jekyll's template post like those created by octopress. I'm looking for any ways to do that and I found [this](http://blog.slaks.net/2013-05-31/migrating-from-blogger-to-jekyll/). After installing blogger2jekyll I got "command not found: blogger2jekyll" message. Any advice?

Thanks from advance!

Comment: Are you sure your `npm install -g blogger2jekyll` worked ?

Comment: @DavidJacquel

I got this error: 
`npm install -g blogger2jekyll
npm ERR! Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/bin/lib/node_modules/blogger2jekyll/.npmignore'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/bin/lib/node_modules/blogger2jekyll/.npmignore']
npm ERR!   errno: 3,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/bin/lib/node_modules/blogger2jekyll/.npmignore' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.`

Then I tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16151018/npm-throws-error-without-sudo) commands but it's still nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your message says : **Please try running this command again as root/Administrator**

`sudo npm install -g blogger2jekyll`

**Edit**: I see in your comment that your symlink is at `/usr/local/bin/bin/blogger2jekyll`.

If `/usr/local/bin/bin/blogger2jekyll path/to/xml destination/path` runs correctly, it's a PATH problem.

The you can `/usr/local/bin/bin` to your path with a :

`export PATH=/usr/local/bin/bin:$PATH`

Comment: I tried this at the very begining and got that:
`/usr/local/bin/bin/blogger2jekyll -> /usr/local/bin/lib/node_modules/blogger2jekyll/bin/blogger2jekyll.js
/usr/local/bin/bin/blogger2jekyll-server -> /usr/local/bin/lib/node_modules/blogger2jekyll/bin/fuzzy-redirect-server.js
blogger2jekyll@1.2.0 /usr/local/bin/lib/node_modules/blogger2jekyll
├── mkdirp@0.3.5
├── xml2js@0.2.8 (sax@0.5.8)
└── connect@2.7.11 (fresh@0.1.0, cookie-signature@1.0.1, pause@0.0.1, qs@0.6.5, bytes@0.2.0, buffer-crc32@0.2.1, cookie@0.0.5, formidable@1.0.14, debug@2.1.1, send@0.1.1)`

And 'command not found'.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm newbie and I would never find it out alone.